# Make CVV code field optional in Authorize.net payment processor in a contribution form

Tags: contribution-page, forms, authorize.net

I have a contribution form with credit card payment. Is there a way to make CVV code OPTIONAL/NOT REQUIRED when an administrator uses contribute to process a credit card transaction?

I tried `hook_civicrm_buildForm()` to unset the rules, but it is not working for me.

I was able to skip CVV validation in CiviCRM backend contribution forms by processing as admin. But I need to skip CVV validation in a contribution form page which will be accessed by users of a specific role.

Answer (score 3):

That’s a configuration/setting ->

CiviCRM -> Adminster -> CiviContribute -> CiviContribute Component Settings

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I have already set this option to No. I was able to skip CVV validation in CiviCRM backend contribution forms.  But I need to skip CVV validation in a contribution form page which will be accessed by users of a specific role.

Comment: CVV codes help prevent credit card fraud. It would generally be a bad idea to remove credit card fraud prevention measures from front facing contribution pages.

Comment: Yeah, I do understand. But it was my client's requirement.

Comment: That’s not a good reason for you to try remove a credit card fraud prevention measure. Read up on CVV eg  https://www.helcim.com/article/card-brands-require-cvv and then go back to and educate your client - surely they don’t want to risk no longer being able to process VISA and steep $ fines and you don’t want to risk your reputation as a CiviCRM developer.